# Cannot find Core dump on Azure Devops Hosted Ubuntu 1604

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, azure-devops, coredump

We have experienced a 'segmentation fault' in test environment on Hosted Ubuntu 1604. However, despite trying to enable various settings, we still cannot get the core dump generated on this hosted machine and it worked fine on one of our local machines.

We have a pipeline yml which define all the build and test script. We have added the following in a script step to enable the generating of core dump.

```
ulimit -c unlimited
sudo systemctl enable apport.service
sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern="core.%p"
```

This script output:

```
sudo systemctl enable apport.service
apport.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable apport
sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=core.%p
kernel.core_pattern = core.%p
core.%p
```

We also have a step to copy all the files from the where the test run, no core dump can be found in the build artefact after the test failed.

Can anyone advise if there is anything else that I need to do in order for the core dump to be generated?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error log, it seems that it executed this script in the wrong file path.

Based on my test, the apport service is under the folder `/etc/init.d/`.

So you could try the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apport start
```

Then the service will start successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your suggestion. The apport service did started successfully, but still no core dump can be found either from the working directory or the '/var/crash' folder. I understand that Ubuntu is using apport to manage the generating of core dump, something else is missing. The service is running ok now, the core_pattern is set to core.%p. All run as sudoer and I even manually introduce a seg fault bug to make sure it failed every run but still seeing no core dump. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @user1622509. From your script, it seems that it may not work if you only define the `core.%p`. You can try to set a specific path.(e.g. `sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t`) Please refer to this Doc:https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/28/debugging-a-segfault-on-linux/

Comment: Hi @Kevin. Thanks. Sorry, I haven't got the chance to look at this issue yet, will try and let you know soon. However core.%p is valid on Linux system and it should just output to the working directory. Will update soon.

Comment: Hi @Kevin. Just an update. It did not work. Still no core dumps found.

Comment: How do you find the core dumps?  Can you try to upload the whole folder as Pipeline Artifacts and check if the core dumps exist.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. That's what I did and no core dumps was found.